# Running npm install and bower install on firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am using firebase hosting service and found that the command npm install and bower install has not been run. As a result, some of my components are missing.

Any way I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting is a static hosting service only. You will need to make sure that the directory you specify in the `firebase.json` file contains all the static files that you want served - probably by having a build step in your deploy process that does the bower install into a build directory before running the `firebase deploy` command